# Join room without camera and microphone

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I use this case on my server: https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC
I'm add text-chat to SimpleWebRtc use

```
 webrtc.sendToAll('chat', {message: msg, nick: webrtc.config.nick});
```

Now i have audio, video and text chat.
But if user join room without camera and without microphone: 
he will not get anything! he can not listen , watch or use the chat.

```
function local media error

webrtc.on('localMediaError', function (err) {
  console.log(err);  
});
```

return "DevicesNotFoundError".
Okay i haven't any devices, but i want use this AWESOME functional.

How i can use it without devices?

Comment: When looking at the ["notsosimple" doc](http://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html), it seems authors will soon add it.

Comment: You might want to use navigator.mediaDevices.enumerate to determine if there are audio or video devices present (and what kinds)
Like for the filetransfer case, you won't get the readyToJoin event since that assumes a camera.

Documentation on the notsosimple page should reflect that soon.

Comment: `DevicesNotFoundError` is Chrome specific. On Firefox it'll be `NotFoundError`.